# Translations in JS files with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, translation

I'm currently developing an applications that will need to use translations from my JavaScripts.

The bundle BazingaJsTranslationBundle seems to be good, but after I tried it I don't think it fits my needs. It generates all the translations for all my application's bundles. It can be heavy to load.

Do you know other bundles or tricks for that ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your exact needs and circumstances, a simple object in json format can be a good enough dictionary. For example like this:

```
var dict = {
    TextIdWelcome : "Welcome",
    TextIdGoodBy : "Good by"
}
```

A usage example:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("WelcomeTag");
elem.innerHtml = dict["TextIdWelcome"];
```

You can generate such json object on your server side for the actual language selected on client side and you can retrieve it by your favourite method (jquery, XMLHttpRequest, etc), and just assign it to this `dict` variable.

If you need sentences with runtime dependent values in it, a simple basic trick might fit your needs. Let use some markup like %0, %1, etc in the translated text.

```
var dict = {
    TextIdWelcome : "Welcome %0",
    TextIdGoodBy : "Good by %0"
}

function tr(textId, runTimeValue1, runTimeValue2){
    var text = dict[textId];
    if(runTimeValue1 !== undefined)
        text = text.replace("%0", runTimeValue1);
    if(runTimeValue2 !== undefined)
        text = text.replace("%1", runTimeValue2);
    return text;
}
```

So a usage example:

```
var userName = "Jhon";
var elem = document.getElementById("WelcomeTag");
elem.innerHtml = tr("TextIdWelcome", userName);
```

Please note that this solution lacks several refined tricks (escaping markups, variable number of runtime values, efficient replace algorithm, etc), but in simple everyday cases this could be good enough. This trick is also very simple (so you can easily enhance it to your needs) and you can control 100% how exactly it should handle the dictionary. You can of course control when and what dictionary to load into the `dict` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes generate and use a json like yours can be usefull. But how do you generate a JSON with all available translations in both app/Resources/translations/messages.fr.php and src/*/Bundle/Resources/translations/messages.fr.php ? Because I might need any translations present in these two files.

I was thinking using one domain per Bundle (for example mybundle.fr.php for the translations in my "MyBundle" bundle. What do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem (large translation files) with BazingaJsTranslationBundle and I simplify this by:

```
#config.yml
bazinga_expose_translation:
    default_domains: [ jsonly ]
    locale_fallback: "%locale%"
```

create simple html twig to store your js variables and bazing expose them from this files

```
{# jsOnleVariables.html.twig #}
{% set var1 = 'Welcome'|trans({},'jsonly') %}
{% set var2 = 'Bye'|trans({},'jsonly') %}
```

dump variables

```
php app/console bazinga:expose-translation:dump web/js
```

and in your layout include only wanted variables

```
{# layout.html.twig #}
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/bazingaexposetranslation/js/translator.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

{% if app.request.locale == 'pl' %}
<script src="{{ asset('js/i18n/jsonly/pl.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% else %}
<script src="{{ asset('js/i18n/jsonly/en.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Of course, the twig idea seemed kind of unorthodox for me to use, so I am using .yml. How many translation keys can you have in js, anyway? The dumper will dump only the domains set in the settings.yml.